# Explain slider code in Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using c# in ASP.net
I have got this code from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/build-image-slider-with-Asp-Net/
It works fine, can some one give small one line description of each line.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var NoofImage = ['http://localhost:64916/images/img1.png', 'http://localhost:64916/images/img2.jpg', 'http://localhost:64916/images/img3.jpg', 'http://localhost:64916/images/img4.jpg'];
        var count = NoofImage.length;
        $(function () { setInterval(Slider, 2000) });
        function Slider()
        {
            $('#imageSlide').fadeIn("slow",function(){$(this).attr('src', NoofImage[(NoofImage.length++)%count]).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think it doesn't takes from database, it is picking images from folder named images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

This line simply loads the jquery library from googlecode.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var NoofImage = ['http://localhost:64916/images/img1.png', 'http://localhost:64916/images/img2.jpg', 'http://localhost:64916/images/img3.jpg', 'http://localhost:64916/images/img4.jpg'];
```

This line instantiates an array of strings to your images. (File locations)

```
    var count = NoofImage.length;
```

Counts the length of your array above

```
    $(function () { setInterval(Slider, 2000) });
```

This runs a function that runs the function "Slider" every 2000 ms (2 seconds)

```
    function Slider()
    {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeIn("slow",function(){$(this).attr('src', NoofImage[(NoofImage.length++)%count]).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
</script>
```

This creates a fade in effect for your images one at a time. It fades in "slow" and runs an inline function that instantiates the image from the URL given in the array at the current number. It uses modulus to go back to the first image after the last image has been reached. This line is dependant on the DOM element "imageSlide".

I hope this answers your question fully enough.

Comment: I have understood it thanks, can you tell more about this line
   
    $('#imageSlide').fadeIn("slow",function(){$(this).attr('src',      NoofImage[(NoofImage.length++)%count]).fadeIn("slow");}

I have understood the thing you told about bringing next image through modulus, but I have not understood rest of the things in this line

Comment: $('#imageSlide') is jquery's way of finding the DOM object with the ID "imageSlide" (In your HTML or so). .fadeIn is a jquery command that is executed on the selected element (imageSlide) followed by some parameters for the function (More here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn). The fade in can take a function take an inline function (function() { ... }) and run this with a fade in effect. Your inline function simply takes the currently selected element (imageSlide) with the "this" statement and gives it a new source (src) for an image, and fade's the new source in (The new image, in other words).